# Refresh list of items after changes in MySql database MVC - live changes on page

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view

I am building an *ASP.NET MVC Web* Application. ***I am using MySql Database as data storage***. On one of the Views, I show the list of matches dragged from the DB. Of course, the user who comes to ***../Matches/Index*** will see only the matches from the moment when he clicked the button to go to the page.

*Is it possible to refresh the page for the user when the displayed data(in this case it's a list of models `[Match]` with few properties) 
changes in any way `= new item added / item deleted` ?*

---

I suppose there is a way of just doing an `Ajax` request in some `interval`, but it's resource consuming. But maybe keeping the constant bond between the server and the client puts even more load than this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**SignalR**](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) which implements [**web sockets**](https://medium.com/@dominik.t/what-are-web-sockets-what-about-rest-apis-b9c15fd72aac) *(constant connection with server; server will send message/response if there are any, even if there is no concurrent request as long as the web socket is established)*.

The response can be retrieved on the client side (JS) so you could modify anything on the current page. It's a popular C# library so you'll find a lot of tutorials here and there.

Comment: forgot, I already edited it -> I use MySql database as the data storage of the app. I coudn't find examples with this type of db and SignalR.

Comment: I believe you could call your data access (any db) in any of the signalr code. Have you tried installing it?